# Flickering Issues with ListScrollView Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I made a scroll list view and get weird flickering issues the text that is centered get very small but I set a font-size to all the items. Also I added a magnifier with the value of 0.1, a diameter radius of 6.5 and a item extent of 200.

Thank you for your help

```
class _CalendarState extends State<Calendar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: ListWheelScrollView(
          children: [
            Text(
              "2020",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2021",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2022",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2023",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2024",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2025",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2026",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2027",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2028",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2029",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            ),
            Text(
              "2030",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 130),
            )
          ],
          itemExtent: 200,
          useMagnifier: true,
          magnification: 0.1,
          diameterRatio: 6.5,clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> change magnification grater then 1.0

magnification property have default value is 1.0, which will not change anything. If the value is > 1.0, the center item will be zoomed in by that rate, and it will also be rendered as flat, not cylindrical like the rest of the list. The item will be zoomed out if magnification < 1.0.